# How can I verify the origin of apple healthkit data?

Tags: ios, digital-signature, healthkit

I want to send users' step counts data to my server for leaderboard of a competition.
But since there are big rewards, there can be cheaters.

I found this (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/samples/adding_digital_signatures?language=objc) in the documentation. But no other information around that.

So how can I get that signature? Is there any metadata written for Apple health records already?
Is there any public key to verify the signature against?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `HKMetadataKeyDigitalSignature` key allows apps that are adding HealthKit samples to add a digital signature to the metadata of samples that they add. It is just a name for that item in the metadata.

HealthKit does not add a digital signature to samples by default.  The app that adding the sample can implement a strategy for signing the sample. It is responsible for managing keys.

From the article you linked to:

> Devices can digitally sign the samples they create, letting other apps validate the samples and verify that they have not been altered. To facilitate this process, HealthKit provides the digital signature metadata key...

There is no way to prevent the user from entering what ever step data they want into HealthKit.

You could use [`CMPedometer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmpedometer) in your app to collect the steps data rather than relying on HealthKit data and then use [App Attestation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/establishing_your_app_s_integrity) to confirm that the data is being submitted to your server by your app.

Comment: very informative, so the app that gets the sample will not get any signature from Healthkit at all, those signatures are for the app that adds the samples, right? I can filter out the manual record, but I'm just worrying about users sending requests to the API directly. In this case, you suggested App Attestation Service, I think that is exactly what I'm looking for. I will verify the result a little bit and mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Great answer.  Also there is an article about detecting fraud server-side from the App Attestation Service, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/assessing_fraud_risk